# Jquery does not select the form element given an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to submit a form with jquery, but it does not acknowledge that I submitted it when I click the "submit" button.

My html is as follows:

```
<form id="singleParam" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sample_size">Number of samples needed</label>
        <input name="choices[sample_size]" type="number" class="form-control" id="sample_size" placeholder="Enter desired number of samples">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mode">Mode of the distribution (value most likely to be sampled)</label>
        <input name="choices[mode]" type="number" class="form-control" id="mode" placeholder="Enter the likeliest value for your parameter">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confidence">Confidence interval factor</label>
        <input name="choices[confidence]" type="number" class="form-control" id="confidence" placeholder="Enter desired confidence interval factor">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit" name="submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

and JS is:

```
$('#singleParam').on('submit', function () {
    alert('Form submitted!');
    console.log('Form submitted!');
    return false;
});
```

The `alert()` or `console.log()` in the loop do not work, meaning that jquery did not run the code on submit. What am I doing wrong? It might be worth mentioning that I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Change the button type from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

**EDIT:-**

Make sure you are calling all your event handlers once the DOM is fully loaded by adding all the code inside dom ready event like:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not solve my problem, the `console.log()` and `alert()` still do not work.

Comment: @cachemoi: Is there any errors in `console` after clicking? Does the form `#singleParam` added dynamically?

Comment: The console does not show any error, and #singleParam is not dynamically added. I tried other, simpler forms given as examples in other websites and they do not work either.

Comment: Currently I can only think of this scenario right now. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/asqpmbuk/  just check if you sumit button js code is inside document ready function or after the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: It was indeed a DOM loading problem, adding `$(document).ready(function() {}` at the beginning of the function solved it. If you want you can write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @cachemoi Done. Hope it helps!